# Index performance for large # documents in Lucene

Tags: solr, elasticsearch, lucene, full-text-search

I have been using `postgresql` for full text search, matching a list of articles against documents containing a particular word. The performance for which degraded with a rise in the no. of rows. I had been using `postgresql` support for full text searches which made the performance faster, but over time resulted in slower searches as the articles increased.

I am just starting to implement with `solr` for searching. Going thru various resources on the net I came across that it can do much more than searching and give me finer control over my results.

`Solr` seems to use an `inverted index`, wouldn't the **performance degrade** over time if many documents (over 1 million) contain a search term begin queried by the user? Also if I am limiting the results via pagination for the searched term, while calculating the `score` for the documents, wouldn't it need to load all of the 1 million+ documents first and then limit the results which would dampen the performance with many documents having the same word?

**Is there a way to sort the index by the score** itself in the first place which would avoid loading of the documents later?

Comment: What did you mean under "it need to load all of the 1 million+ documents first"? It does not load any document during searching or sorting

Comment: Wouldn't it need to load all of the documents or calculate the `scoring` which includes factors `idf (inverse document frequency)`, `coord factor` for a million of them?

Comment: What score would you want to store in the index? For which query? You want to pre-calculate all possible scores for all possible queries and store them? Just with 10 different words, this would result in 3.628.800 different queries with different scores ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lucene has been designed to solve all the problems you mentioned. Apart from inverted index, there is also posting lists, docvalues, separation of indexed and stored value, and so on.

And then you have Solr on top of that to add even more goodies.

And 1 million documents is an introductory level problem for Lucene/Solr. It is being routinely tested on indexing a Wikipedia dump.

If you feel you actually need to *understand* how it works, rather than just be *reassured* about this, check books on Lucene, including the old ones. Also check Lucene Javadocs - they often have additional information.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose `fieldcache` coupled with various other store features would be sufficient to overcome such problems, just so I meant, a single term having a million docs